# How to check if navigation to next UIViewController has occurred or not in ios?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I have used a storyboard and dragged the navigations between controllers . E.g From `UIViewController` A to `UIViewController` B to `UIViewController` C.

I have a button on `UIViewController` A. I am using that button and linking an action dragging to `UIViewController` B and setting the segue to push type.

Then on the button Click,I am checking some condition like this :

```
    if( go == YES )
    {
      // navigate to B
    }
    else
    {
     // don't navigate to B
    }
```

How can I write the code to properly navigate to B or stop navigating to B?
Do I have to use `prepareForSegue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till here, you have done it correctly. Now try these steps :

1. The segue that you have connected by dragging from A to B, set the segueIdentifier for it in the Interface Builder.
2. In your button click method, use this statement when you want to navigate from A to B.

   > [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];

Here you will have to provide the identifier name that you set in the Interface builder.

Your problem is that you have directly connected the button to push Segue to the B Controller. To stop navigating to B when condition is false, follow these steps :

1. Delete the current Segue from A to B.
2. Now Connect a segue from the ViewController button of the View in your storyboard to the B Controller. Look out for this yellow button below your A ViewController. See that yellow button at the bottom image. Connect a segue by dragging from that button to your B ViewController.

[image]

3. Now name that Segue with the name you gave before i.e loginSegue and try running your project. Now it won't go to B if condition is false.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank your response. But I still navigation to B UIViewController. I had set condition in IBAction.  
if(check == YES )
    {
        NSLog(@"yes");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }
Can you check my simple code at the sample? my git is https://github.com/dickfala/navigationTest.git 
.

Comment: Will Check and get back to you on this.

Comment: See my updated answer. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `prepareForSegue` every time.
You can also push view controller by this code.

```
if( go == YES )
    {
      // navigate to B

        UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        viewController *viewObj = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewObj animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
     // don't navigate to B
    }
```

For this you have to give storyboardID to `viewcontroller` as "viewController" in your storyboard.